# Html Checkbox within anker IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, checkbox

i have the following html page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testpage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#">
        <input type="checkbox">
        someText
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

When i open this in firefox (10.0.2) and click on the checkbox the dash is append to the url. If i do this in IE9 nothing happens. If i however click on the text "someText" it works in both browsers. It is a very simple Problem but i could not find any solution, and could not understand this behavior. I hope somebody can help me.

kukudas

Comment: A `input` element in an anchor would be invalid HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding an **onclick** event to the check box. Here is an example:

```
<a href="#">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="document.location.href='#'">
    someText
</a>
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: Luca is correct that you should not use a checkbox in an anchor tag.

Comment: i used a similar solution. To have valid HTML i put the input element outside of the href. But i still used the onclick event to execute the link.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can't use input inside anchor tag. Try to include only text or images inside an anchor tag, and move the checkbox outside.
See http://forums.htmlhelp.com/index.php?showtopic=13273